# addSubView behaviour with properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to get a handle on what's happening in my app...

I have a UICollectionViewCell subclass which has a UIImageView as a property.

In that subclass's init method, I programatically add the imageView property as a subView of the classes contentView:

```
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
```

At the point this happens, the 'self.imageView' property is null as the imageView has not been created and assigned to the property yet.

Later in my cellForItemAtIndexPath method, I assign the imageView property of the cell equal to an imageView object.

At this point I expect that the content view would now have a valid imageView subclass, but that's not what i'm seeing.

So my question is: Why doesn't it work?

Should I be able to add my 'null' property imageView as a subView of my self.contentView and then later assign the imageView property equal to an imageView object, and then see that object as one of the contentViews subviews?

I hope this question makes sense, it was a pain to describe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't (and you see it doesn't work). A property is a reference to an instance of something. If that instance doesn't exist yet then you can't work with it. Trying to isn't setting up some rule for future use, it's just quietly doing nothing.

You can add a method like `configureImageView:` and call that instead. The implementation would set the property and add the image view as a subview.

Comment: many thanks for the information, I overrode the setting of the imageView property to also add as a subView, I think this is a good solution?

Comment: It depends what you're doing. I like the other answer in many ways (+1'd) - why pass the image view in instead of just the image?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a subview which is nil sounds wrong to me

I think you are using a wrong approach. You should instantiate and add your imageView in your cell´s init method and then, in the cellForItemAtIndexPath of your controller assign the image like this

```
cell.imageView.image = the image you want...
```